# GTX Titan Z Global Memory

Tags: cuda, gpu

I have a GTX Titan Z graphics card. It has twin GPUs with total memory of 12 GB (6GB + 6GB). When I use DeviceQuery application in Cuda Sample (V6.5) folder to see the specification, it shows two devices, each having total memory of 4 GB. Furthermore, in my C++ code I can only access to 4GB memory. On the other hand, when I run GPU-Z software, it shows two Titan Zs, each having 6GB memory. Could anyone explain what has caused this problem and how can be resolved?

Comment: What OS are you running? 32/64 bit?

Comment: Are you using an "express" version of Visual Studio to compile the apps?  If so, the express versions only have support for creating 32-bit executables (both host and device code) and therefore you will run into the 4GB limitation.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 professional version. Considering your comment, I changed the configuration for the platform type to 64, and the problem was resolved. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jez you pointed out the 32/64 bit issue.  If you want to provide an answer I would upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here was that the program was being compiled as a 32-bit application. With 32 bits the program is only able to address 4GB of memory. The CUDA call to check device specifications (`cudaGetDeviceProperties`) appears to recognize this fact, and only reports the 4GB you can actually use.

Compiling as a 64-bit application should resolve this problem.